# Why is this bash/CURL call to REST services giving inconsistent results with parameters?

Tags: bash, rest, curl

I have written a smoke-testing script that uses BASH script & Curl to test RESTful web services we're working on.  The script reads a file, and interprets each line as a URL suffix and parameters for a Curl REST call.

**Unfortunately, the script gives unexpected results** when I adapted it to run HTTP POST calls as well as GET calls.  It does not give the same results running the command on its own, vs. in script:

**The BASH Script:**

```
IFS=$'\n' #Don't split an input URL line at spaces
RESTHOST='hostNameAndPath' #Can't give this out

URL="/activation/v2/activationInfo --header 'Content-Type:Application/xml'"
URL2="/activation/v2/activationInfo"

OUTPUT=`curl -sL -m 30 -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null $RESTHOST$URL -d @"./activation_post.txt" -X POST`
echo 'out:' $OUTPUT

OUTPUT2=`curl -sL -m 30 -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null $RESTHOST$URL2 --header 'Content-Type:Application/xml' -d @'./activation_post.txt' -X POST`
echo 'out2:' $OUTPUT2
```

**Results Out:**

> out: 505
>   out2: 200

So, **the first call fails** (HTTP return code 505, HTTP Version Not Supported), and the **second call succeeds** (return code "OK").

**Why does the first call fail, and how do I fix it?**  I've verified they should execute the same command (evaluating in echo).  I am sure there is something basic I'm missing, as I am just NOW learning Bash scripting.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the command before you run it, to make sure it's the same as what you're running on the command line?

Comment: @ChrisHenry: Of course, first thing I did. Echoing the string in backticks gives matching results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem! It is caused by `IFS=$'\n'`! Because of this, variable expansion does not work as expected. It does not let to split the arguments specified in the URL string!

As a result the `SERVER_PROTOCOL` variable on the server side will be set to '--header Content-Type:Application/xml HTTP/1.1' instead of "HTTP/1.1", and the `CONTENT_TYPE` will be 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of 'Application/xml'.

To show the root of the problem in detail:

```
VAR="Solaris East"
printf "+%s+ " $VAR
echo "==="
IFS=$'\n'
printf "+%s+ " $VAR
```

Output:

```
+Solaris+ +East+ ===
+Solaris East+
```

**So the `$VAR` expansion does not work as expected because of `IFS=$'\n'`!**

**Solution:** Do not use `IFS=$'\n'` and replace space to `%20` in URL!

```
URL=${URL2// /%20}" --header Content-Type:Application/xml"
```

In this case your first [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) call will work properly!

If You still use `IFS=$'\n'` and give `--header` option in the command line it will not work properly if `URL` contains a space, because the server will fail to process it (I tested on [apache](/questions/tagged/apache))!

Even You still cannot use `HEADER="--header Content-Type:Application/xml"` as expanding `$HEADER` will result one(!) argument for [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), namely `--header Content-Type:Application/xml` instead of splitting them into two.

So I may suggest to replace spaces in URL to `%20` anyway!

Comment: Brilliant! That makes sense now -- tested it just now, and it works. I'm using $IFS because am reading in lines from file with cat into an array of URLS/params strings (one per line).  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @BobMcGee: Sure. You can read a file like this: `while read x; do arr+=("$x");done <infile`. Or you can immediately convert spaces to `%20` as `while read x; do arr+=("${x// /%20}");done <infile` (then `"` may be left off).

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes surrounding `Content-Type:Application/xml`, because they are quoted in the value of `URL` are treated as literal quotes and not removed when `$URL` is expanded in that call to `curl`. As a result, you are passing an invalid HTTP header. Just use

```
URL="/activation/v2/activationInfo --header Content-Type:Application/xml"
OUTPUT=`curl -sL -m 30 -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null $RESTHOST$URL -d @"./activation_post.txt" -X POST`
```

However, it's not a great idea to rely on word-splitting like this to combine two separate pieces of the call to `curl` in a single variable. Try something like this instead:

```
URLPATH="activation/v2/activationInfo"
HEADERS=("--header" "Content-Type:Application/xml")
OUTPUT=$( curl -SL -m 30 -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null "$RESTHOST/$URL" "${HEADERS[@]}"  -d @'./activation_post.txt' -X POST )
```

Comment: I tried the first approach.  If I do it the way you suggest (for the first part), the command comes out with an unquoted string for the content-type, which causes problems.  Unfortunately, the second way of doing it isn't usable (this is a small segment of something else).

Comment: @BobMcGee: I'm curious, what kind of problems caused in the first case? IMHO it is a single word, so `bash` interprets it as a single argument.

Comment: @TrueY Well I can't speak to the root cause, but with this change, it is not fixed.

Comment: Please be specific about what problems you are having. I can't fix what I can't reproduce.

Comment: @chepner: I think I found the problem!

Comment: Problem fixed, it was a combination of both things, so +1 here too.